# How can I render images in the footer and header of my pdf in NESTJS / html-pdf?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, html-pdf

I am trying to generate a pdf through this service in NestJS, the file is generated correctly, the problem is when I try to use an image as logo and an image in the footer, I am using the html-pdf library and I have followed its documentation For this, I place a text in the header and footer part and it automatically places it in all the pdf pages, the problem is that when I try to place images, only the white space appears, this is my code, Thanks!

```
 const pdfOptions: pdf.CreateOptions = {
      format: 'Letter',
      border: {
        top: '0',
        right: '0',
        bottom: '0',
        left: '0',
      },
      header: {
        height: '10mm',
        contents:
          '<img src="ExampleUrl.com" alt="Logo">',
      },
      footer: {
        height: "28mm",
        contents: {
          default:'<img src="ExampleUrl.com" alt="footer">',
        }
      },
    };
```

i tried to embe the image via html